# Making fixed div expand between elements

Tags: html, css

I have a div that should be between two elements: A header and a footer. This div is a side menu and it needs to be fixed with 100% height that way however the user scrolls, it will always follow them. However, I cannot get the menu to be between the header and footer. It will go on top of the footer and header. I don't want to use z-index: 0, because the side menu will contain items. I need it to start at the end of the header and beginning of the footer. Also, I chose static heights here, but the real world example has auto heights for footer and header. Here's how it looks like now: https://jsfiddle.net/kt29L1ef/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
}

.menu {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #222;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">


</div>
<div class="menu">

</div>

<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible, unless header and footer also have fixed position. or if you use a Grid layout, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question rather intriguing. The cool, weird thing about a `fixed` position element is how it behaves when you don't specify a positioning property (`top`, `bottom`, etc.). It remains statically positioned (but fixed to that position), which happens to be just where we want it. Using that knowledge, and adding some flexbox into the mix, I think I achieved what you're looking for. Since I couldn't explicitly extend the height of thte `fixed` menu, I used its full height parent container to house the background color, making it appear as if it belongs to the menu.

**Demo notes:**

- View in 'Full page' mode (or in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d50x8my/5/))
- I made the `.header` and `.footer` short, but their height is irrelevant. The `main` element will always consume the most available space

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.fixed {
  padding-left: .75em;
  flex: 2.8;
  background-color: #222;
  box-shadow: 0.2rem 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.content {
  flex: 10;
  padding-left: 1.3em;
}

.menu {
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header"></div>
  
  <main>
    <div class="fixed">
      <div class="menu">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus nostrum mollitia ea ut debitis natus, hic rem quo et harum dignissimos error alias saepe vitae doloribus dicta repellat illo repudiandae!</span></p>
      <p><span>Quisquam ut unde, dolorum id vero autem cumque fuga quos. Natus fuga consequuntur odit, officiis velit sequi nisi. Vel nam est, at laborum dignissimos. Accusamus nulla sint enim officia tenetur?</span>
        <span>Labore quas dolores, quisquam impedit rerum, ipsam earum, voluptates dolorem delectus sequi architecto cupiditate eum quasi, amet officia totam tenetur provident iure repellat ex eligendi repudiandae a! Minima, nulla minus.</span></p>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus nostrum mollitia ea ut debitis natus, hic rem quo et harum dignissimos error alias saepe vitae doloribus dicta repellat illo repudiandae!</span>
        <span>Quisquam ut unde, dolorum id vero autem cumque fuga quos. Natus fuga consequuntur odit, officiis velit sequi nisi. Vel nam est, at laborum dignissimos. Accusamus nulla sint enim officia tenetur?</span>
        <span>Labore quas dolores, quisquam impedit rerum, ipsam earum, voluptates dolorem delectus sequi architecto cupiditate eum quasi, amet officia totam tenetur provident iure repellat ex eligendi repudiandae a! Minima, nulla minus.</span></p>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus nostrum mollitia ea ut debitis natus, hic rem quo et harum dignissimos error alias saepe vitae doloribus dicta repellat illo repudiandae!</span>
        <span>Quisquam ut unde, dolorum id vero autem cumque fuga quos. Natus fuga consequuntur odit, officiis velit sequi nisi. Vel nam est, at laborum dignissimos. Accusamus nulla sint enim officia tenetur?</span>
        <span>Labore quas dolores, quisquam impedit rerum, ipsam earum, voluptates dolorem delectus sequi architecto cupiditate eum quasi, amet officia totam tenetur provident iure repellat ex eligendi repudiandae a! Minima, nulla minus.</span></p>
      <p><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus nostrum mollitia ea ut debitis natus, hic rem quo et harum dignissimos error alias saepe vitae doloribus dicta repellat illo repudiandae!</span>
        <span>Quisquam ut unde, dolorum id vero autem cumque fuga quos. Natus fuga consequuntur odit, officiis velit sequi nisi. Vel nam est, at laborum dignissimos. Accusamus nulla sint enim officia tenetur?</span>
        <span>Labore quas dolores, quisquam impedit rerum, ipsam earum, voluptates dolorem delectus sequi architecto cupiditate eum quasi, amet officia totam tenetur provident iure repellat ex eligendi repudiandae a! Minima, nulla minus.</span></p>
    </div>
  </main>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6d50x8my/5/)